# How to improve OCR quality using Tesseract?

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am extracting image matrices using opencv from a desktop application screenshot and using tesseract to read the cropped images. For instance, if you refer to the images below, Tesseract extracts "Relationship" image to be R’e‘auunshwp and member as Mamba!

Is the quality of attaching image too low for tesseract? What can I do to improve it?

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE**

I used the following code to resize image, which improved OCR quality. But, how do I calculate what would be 300DPI and then how do I ensure that the aspect ratio of the image remains the same at the scale?

```
    Mat resizedMat = new Mat();
    Size sz = new Size(mat.rows()*10,mat.cols()*10);
    Imgproc.resize(mat,resizedMat,sz);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolution is too low. Try rescaling to 300DPI.

Comment: I tried resizing with the code mentioned in the updated question - it did great with half of the images - OCR works better, but half of them still fail. I think I need to retain the aspect ratio, the resizing looks ugly with my code.

Comment: I am trying to understand 300DPI in this context. What I have is a cropped image of a desktop application screenshot, which probably measures 1300x768 and the cropped text is approximately 100x20-30 or less. I thought DPI meant print quality, and depending on the what area you are printing to, the image size could be calculated, but if I am not printing, how do I understand 300 DPI for my cropped images?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it with this code, using OpenCV -

```
Mat resizedMat = new Mat();
double width = mat.cols();
double height = mat.rows();
double aspect = width / height;
Size sz = new Size(width * aspect * 2, height * aspect * 2);
Imgproc.resize(mat, resizedMat, sz);
```

Comment: may be I wasn't clear in my comments, I was using opencv in java to do the resizing above.

Answer (score 1):

As nguyenq said, you should rescale your image, because tesseract struggles to scan low quality images.

I answered a similar question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677638/is-it-normal-that-tesseract-does-not-recognize-this-word-in-this-image) for another person, you should try to do the same. Increase your image size by 200-400%, if only this does not help, do some blurring and then threshold.